# Clean and install only modified modules

Tags: maven

Is it possible to clean and install only modules which has changed?

I mean I have

moduleA
moduleB - changed
moduleC
moduleD - changed
moduleE

then

maven clean install changed (module B and D)

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. What if module B introduced changes which breaks module A ?

Comment: so the question is how to clean install only this modules which have you changed and has impact on others

Comment: I cannot vouch for stability, but you might want to have a look at https://github.com/khmarbaise/incremental-module-builder